# Django REST: How to access the POST request object

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a POST request to the server using axios in React.js .I have no errors sending the object from the front end to the back end (when the request is sent, Django returns 200). Nevertheless, I can't access the object's information: I have several fields, one of them is 'name'. When I try:

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def join_us(request):
    print(request.POST.get('name')) #This returns None
    return Response('test ')
```

**form.js**

```
  formHandler=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({loading:true});

    const data = {...this.state};
    console.log(data); //This print the object information, nothing is wrong here
    axios.post('https://127.0.1.1:8000/api/join_us/', data)
  }
```

What is the right way to access the sent object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSONParser is missing.

In **views.py**

```
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser 

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def join_us(request):
    data= JSONParser().parse(request)
    print(data) #It will return the object
    return Response('test')
```